# About builtin command puzzle

Tags: bash, command, built-in

```
[root@MGWSDT_FEWS bin]# type cd
cd is a shell builtin
[root@MGWSDT_FEWS bin]# which cd
/usr/bin/which: no cd in (.:/usr/expect/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/real/RealPlayer:/root/bin)
```

It says that because cd is a builtin command, so 'which cd' failed.

'pwd' is also a builtin command, why 'which pwd' can get its location?

```
[root@MGWSDT_FEWS ~]# type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
[root@MGWSDT_FEWS ~]# which pwd
/bin/pwd
```

Comment: Depending on your shell then the commands are implemented differently. Look at `man type` to see how it is implemented

Answer (score 1):

Understand that for `sudo` or any other command that is not a shell builtin, when the command terminates, the shell picks up where it left off before the command was run (of course, the shell's current working directory won't change). As such, `cd` must be a shell builtin; otherwise, when `cd` terminates, the shell is back to the same old current working directory. In other words, a child process (i.e. an external command) can't change the working directory of the parent process (i.e. the shell).

Courtesy: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127225

Answer (score 0):

cd command is bash's command. (bash built in command)

You can find cd's usage in "man bash & find cd"

Contrary, pwd is standalone command.

Answer (score 0):

Builtin commands are internal commands in the shell and has a higher priority over external commands (files). And builtin commands also have lower priority than functions so builtin is actually helpful if you have a function with the same name as the builtin command like this:

```
function cd {
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo "Changing directory to $1."
        builtin cd "$1"
    else
        echo "Changing to default directory."
        builtin cd
    fi
}

cd "/some/where"
```

As a summary functions gets called first before builtins, and builtins gets called first before binary commands or files. The type command I think would also follow that order when interpreting an argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are several instances where "commands" are duplicated, but of course this will depend on your installation.  If you have a shell built-in called `pwd` then that will be used, but there might be shells (`csh`) that do not have `pwd` as a built-in.

`printf` is a shell built-in for `bash` and `ksh93` but not for `ksh88` or `csh`.

Another (weirder) example is `[`, which is a shell built-in but (on some systems) a symbolic link to `test` (which might also be a shell built-in).

Your installation is there to support many shells and other programs, not just `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

cd has to be shell-built-in, because it were a separate process, then the effect of the command would have vanished, after the command exits. (See Sakthi Kumar's answer.)

On the other hand, some other commands like `pwd`, `test` are available as binaries, like `/bin/pwd`, `/usr/bin/test`... However, for optimization, shell has also implementation of these binaries within /bin/bash itself, so that the overhead of creating a separate process is avoided.

when you call `pwd`, shell calls its own `pwd` implementation. You can call the binary `/bin/pwd` using `command pwd` instead of just `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

Commands such as `pwd` and `echo` are bash-builtins and also available as external commands.  You can use `enable` to enable/disable shell builtins.

The following example iillustrates how `pwd` can be invoked either as a shell-builtin or as external command i.e. `/bin/pwd`.

```
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
$ which pwd
/bin/pwd
$ enable -n pwd
$ type pwd
pwd is /bin/pwd
$ which pwd
/bin/pwd
$ enable pwd
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
$ which pwd
/bin/pwd
```